# How to compare two timestamp columns in a Gremlin Java query

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp, gremlin

Is there a way to do something like that in Gremlin traversals?
I would have thought it would be obvious, but it seems I was wrong.
I have a table containing two dates (both are timestamps), and I would like to select only the records having one greater than the other one. Something like:

```
has('date_one', P.gt('date_two'))
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone > character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Then the second argument is not translated into the value of the column 'date_two'.

Based on the answer 1, the full request becomes:

```
g.V().hasLabel('File').where(or (
__.out('has_Ref1').hasNot('date_one'), 
__.out('has_Ref1').as('s1', 's2').where('s1', gt('s2')).by('date_two').by('date_one')))
.as('file').out('has_Ref1').as('ref1').out('has_Content').as('data').select('file','ref1','data')
But in this case: A where()-traversal must have at least a start or end label (i.e. variable): [OrStep([[VertexStep(OUT,[has_Ref1],vertex), NotStep([PropertiesStep([date_one],value)])], [VertexStep(OUT,[has_Ref1],vertex)@[s1, s2], WherePredicateStep(s1,gt(s2),[value(date_two), value(date_one)])]])]
```

I guess the second argument of the or clause must be a boolean. Then if I try to add '.hasNext()', I've got the following exception:

```
g.V().hasLabel('File').where(or (
__.out('has_Ref1').hasNot('date_one'), 
__.out('has_Ref1').as('s1', 's2').where('s1', gt('s2')).by('date_two').by('date_one').hasNext()))
.as('file').out('has_Ref1').as('ref1').out('has_Content').as('data').select('file','ref1','data')
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.or() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal...) values: [[VertexStep(OUT,[has_Ref1],vertex), NotStep([PropertiesStep([date_one],value)])], ...]
```

Comment: The error suggests that your "real" query is different than the one you wrote in question. I suspect the `asg.modifiedAt` should be `modifiedAt`? Also, are you sure that *both* values exist on *all* Ref nodes?Maybe it is better to check values exist prior the comparison.

Comment: I'm not sure all values exist. The condition is "select if date_one is null OR if date_two > date_one

Comment: So there is a possibility that date_one is defined, but date_two is null and it will fail. Maybe check that date_two is not null as well. What about the asg prefix? By the way, which DB server are you using?

Comment: date_two is never null. You can forget the prefix, it is not the concern here. The problem is just "select File having a link 'has_Ref1' if ref1.date_one is null or ref1.date_one < ref1.date_two"

Answer (score 0):

The `has()` step doesn't quite work that way as the `P` deals with a constant value supplied to it and doesn't treat that value as a property key. You would want to use `where()` step in this case I think so that you could take advantage of [traversal induced values](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-induced-values):

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('d1',1).property('d2',2).
......1>   addV('person').property('d1',2).property('d2',1).iterate()
gremlin> g.V().as('x','y').where('x', gt('y')).by('d1').by('d2').elementMap()
==>[id:3,label:person,d1:2,d2:1]
```

Comment: Thx. I did not get we may compare against different values .by('d1').by('d2'). I'm still have issues there, perhaps because the condition is yet in a where clause:".where(or ("
 + "__.out('has_Ref').hasNot('date_one'), "
 + "__.out('has_Ref').as('s1', 's2').where('s1', gt('s2')).by('date_two').by('date_one')))";

Comment: I'm not so sure that I follow your problem anymore. You may need to edit your question to include some sample data and more of your actual traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask Postgres if the `data_one` is bigger than `date_two`

```sql
SELECT '2019-11-20'::timestamp > '2019-11-01'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

Time: 10.246 ms
```

> this provides you a boolean value

Comment: You're right. I tested it directly in pgAdmin. But the context I have to use is Gremlin' queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about a columns in a single table.
I have mostly worked with graphDB with gremlin but I think it will still fit right.

do your thing to get the table of concern
`g.V().has(...).has()...`

then just project the same data twice by using `project` directly or using `as` & `select`
`...as('named1', 'named2').select('named1')`

it is creating two copies of same data in the flow and then you can compare them on different basis like
`...where('named1', gt('named2')).by('value1').by('value2')`

above part in literal english means that bring me only those from selected where value1 of named1 is greater than value2 of named2
If you give only one `by` then it will compare same property